# Armadillo: element-wise logical AND between two matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

Is there a way to combine the result of two logical operations in armadillo?
In matlab, assuming a matrix `A` and two conditions, it would be done like this:

```
B = (A == 1) & (A == 2)
```

where `B` is the matrix where `A` is equal to 1 and 2.
I found a workaround in Armadillo:

```
umat B = ((A == 1) + (A == 2)) == 2
```

or

```
umat B = ((A == 1) % (A == 2))
```

which works, but I am sure there is a more efficient way to do that, which I haven't found yet.